# Why doesn't `brew install --cask --HEAD emacs` give me the latest GUI Emacs?

Tags: install

for macOS
What if I want the latest emacs, and gui too,
why isn't "brew install --cask --HEAD emacs" allowed?

I get:
Error: Invalid usage: Options --cask and --HEAD are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about a tool called `brew`, which is not part of Emacs. You should ask for help with this tool in a forum dedicated to the tool.